# Trouble with a join

Tags: sql-server, join

[image: Currency] 
[image: Store_location]

I have two tables, 'Currency' and 'Store_location' . I need to find out the currency conversion rate, which is stored in 'Currency' via the store's location, which is in 'Store_location.' I tried the below, and it displays no data:

```
SELECT Currency.currency_name,Currency.us_dollars_to_currency_ratio 
from Currency JOIN Store_location
ON Store_location.currency_accepted_id = Currency.currency_id
WHERE Store_location.store_name = 'Cancun Extension'
```

Not sure what I'm missing. I've tried left joins, right joins, full joins. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of using the name in the where clause, try using the store_locaton_id instead, let us know if it works or not.

Comment: The issue was white space between 'Cancun' and 'Extension'. I updated it so there was no extra white space and now my query works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Shaulinator suggested the issue was white space, and was correct. When doing LIKE 'Cancun%Extension', it produced a row. I removed the white space and the query now works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any problem with your `JOIN` but your `WHERE` clause is using 'Cancun Connection' instead of 'Cancun Extension' - which is indicated by the image that you posted. Unless that row does exist and is just not included in your post of course. Other than that your query is fine, see this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84233/1) based on your example above which returns data.

Comment: Oops. Yeah it should be Extension not Connection, but I get the same result with both. Any ideas?

Comment: There is nothing directly wrong with your `JOIN` based on the snippets you have posted. Have you tried running it without the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: That shows all currency names and their ratios, and I need it to find the currency for the location in the query. I'm not sure what's wrong. I verified store_name is VARCHAR(255), so I know it's not a truncation issue.  The currency_id is 5 on both tables, so those should link up fine. But when I search for 'Cancun Extension', the result is empty.

Comment: I added a sql fiddle as an example using the information you provided. It works fine.

Comment: Perhaps it's just SQL server that it doesn't work on?

Comment: I just ran it on 2008, 2012, 2014 and 2016. Worked every time. Maybe a collation problem on your server/tables?

Comment: Do you get any error message? Or the query run successfully with zero rows returned? What result you get if your run SELECT * FROM store_location where Store_location.store_name = 'Cancun Extension'? In the picture I do not see a under score in the 'Store_location' table name.

Comment: Maybe there's a white space at the end of Extension? What does LIKE '%Cancun Extension' return?

Comment: @SqlWorldWide, no errors, it returns 0 rows. When I did the query you suggested, it also returns 0 rows. Shaulinator, it looks like there may be white space in the middle. I tried LIKE 'Cancun%Extension' and it returned a row. I think we found the problem, I'll try altering the row and see if that works. UPDATE: I updated 'Cancun Extension' and now it works. It was in fact white space in the middle.